# How do I access the local storage of a URL that I am not currently connected to?

Tags: javascript, browser, local-storage

JavaScript beginner here.

Is there a way to access the local storage of another URL when I am not actively visiting that site?

If I am on https://www.youtube.com/ and I go to local storage on my browser (Chrome in this case), there are two separate URLs there, one for https://www.youtube.com/ and one for https://accounts.youtube.com/.

I don't know how to go about accessing this "secondary" local storage, or whatever you would call it, for a website.

For example, when I go to youtube.com, this is what the local storage looks like:

[image: Local Storage Image]

**Note the two separate URLs in the Local Storage tab.**

Each URL has its own respective local storage, with different values in each.

Local storage for https://www.youtube.com/:

[image: Local Storage for youtube.com]

Local storage for https://accounts.youtube.com/:

[image: Local Storage for accounts.youtube.com]

How would I go about accessing `localStorage["foo"]` from accounts.youtube.com?

Currently, `localStorage["foo"]` would just be `undefined`, because it is looking at the local storage for the primary url (https://www.youtube.com/) but I want to somehow access the "secondary" URL (https://accounts.youtube.com/)

So is there any way for me to access this "secondary" storage using JavaScript, or am I simply looking at this the wrong way/misunderstanding something?

Comment: That is not possible; localStorage is tied to the _origin_ of the current document, and `https://www.youtube.com/` and `https://accounts.youtube.com/` are simply different origins.

Comment: Nope, there's not a way to do that.  If this were possible it would be a security issue where any website could access saved data from any other website.  Check out [the MDN docs on how to use the localstorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#examples). it's fairly simple.

Comment: In what context are you trying to do this?  If you're visiting YouTube and want to observe the values across different subdomains, the inspector you're showing is how you'd manually do that.  Or do you also have code on *your site* which is doing this, and you want to access subdomain data *on your site*?  Or are you talking about some browser extension you're trying to write for when you visit YouTube?  Or something else?  For code you control there are various approaches to take, but it's not really clear what the underlying intent is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, this is not possible. It's by design for security. Here is a pretty decent article that covers the same origin policy, localStorage, and sessionStorage.

https://auth0.com/blog/secure-browser-storage-the-facts/